# NIntegrate and Integrate give different results

Tags: calculus-and-analysis, numerical-integration

Good morning, I computed the following integral

```
Integrate[1/(\[Pi]^3 (I u + y))
I (-1 + 
 t^2) (-(((1 - 6 t^2 + t^4 + 8 t Z - 4 Z^2) ArcTan[(-I + I t^2 + 
    2 t u - 2 u Z)/Sqrt[
   1 + t^4 + 4 t^3 y + 4 y Z + 4 Z^2 - 4 t (y + 2 Z) + 
    t^2 (2 - 4 y Z)]])/((-1 + t^2) (1 + t^4 + 4 t^3 y + 4 y Z + 
    4 Z^2 - 4 t (y + 2 Z) + t^2 (2 - 4 y Z))^(3/2)))), u, Assumptions -> u \[Element] Reals && t > -1 && t < 1 && y > -1 && y < 1 && 
Z > 1] // Simplify
```

the result is

```
(I (1 - 6 t^2 + t^4 + 8 t Z - 
 4 Z^2) (Log[(
   2 (I u + y) (t - Z))/(-1 + t^2 + 2 t y - 2 y Z - Sqrt[
    1 + t^4 + 4 t^3 y + 4 y Z + 4 Z^2 - 4 t (y + 2 Z) + 
     t^2 (2 - 4 y Z)])] Log[(
   1 - t^2 + 2 I t u - 2 I u Z + Sqrt[
    1 + t^4 + 4 t^3 y + 4 y Z + 4 Z^2 - 4 t (y + 2 Z) + 
     t^2 (2 - 4 y Z)])/Sqrt[
   1 + t^4 + 4 t^3 y + 4 y Z + 4 Z^2 - 4 t (y + 2 Z) + 
    t^2 (2 - 4 y Z)]] - 
 Log[(-1 + t^2 - 2 I t u + 2 I u Z + Sqrt[
    1 + t^4 + 4 t^3 y + 4 y Z + 4 Z^2 - 4 t (y + 2 Z) + 
     t^2 (2 - 4 y Z)])/Sqrt[
   1 + t^4 + 4 t^3 y + 4 y Z + 4 Z^2 - 4 t (y + 2 Z) + 
    t^2 (2 - 4 y Z)]] Log[(
   2 (I u + y) (t - Z))/(-1 + t^2 + 2 t y - 2 y Z + Sqrt[
    1 + t^4 + 4 t^3 y + 4 y Z + 4 Z^2 - 4 t (y + 2 Z) + 
     t^2 (2 - 4 y Z)])] - 
 PolyLog[2, (-1 + t^2 - 2 I t u + 2 I u Z + Sqrt[
   1 + t^4 + 4 t^3 y + 4 y Z + 4 Z^2 - 4 t (y + 2 Z) + 
    t^2 (2 - 4 y Z)])/(-1 + t^2 + 2 t y - 2 y Z + Sqrt[
   1 + t^4 + 4 t^3 y + 4 y Z + 4 Z^2 - 4 t (y + 2 Z) + 
    t^2 (2 - 4 y Z)])] + 
 PolyLog[2, (
  1 - t^2 + 2 I t u - 2 I u Z + Sqrt[
   1 + t^4 + 4 t^3 y + 4 y Z + 4 Z^2 - 4 t (y + 2 Z) + 
    t^2 (2 - 4 y Z)])/(
  1 - t^2 - 2 t y + 2 y Z + Sqrt[
   1 + t^4 + 4 t^3 y + 4 y Z + 4 Z^2 - 4 t (y + 2 Z) + 
    t^2 (2 - 4 y Z)])]))/(2 \[Pi]^3 (1 + t^4 + 4 t^3 y + 4 y Z + 
 4 Z^2 - 4 t (y + 2 Z) + t^2 (2 - 4 y Z))^(3/2))
```

However when i compute a definite integral using this expression and compare to the NIntegrate result i get a different answer. For example:

```
In[108]:= NIntegrate[(1/(\[Pi]^3 (I u + y))
 I (-1 + 
  t^2) (-(((1 - 6 t^2 + t^4 + 8 t Z - 4 Z^2) ArcTan[(-I + I t^2 + 
     2 t u - 2 u Z)/Sqrt[
    1 + t^4 + 4 t^3 y + 4 y Z + 4 Z^2 - 4 t (y + 2 Z) + 
     t^2 (2 - 4 y Z)]])/((-1 + t^2) (1 + t^4 + 4 t^3 y + 4 y Z + 
     4 Z^2 - 4 t (y + 2 Z) + t^2 (2 - 4 y Z))^(3/2))))) /. {t -> 
0.7, y -> 0.25, Z -> 1.7}, {u, -5, 10}] Out[108]= -0.0579211 - 0.000454007 I
```

whereas

```
In[109]:= (result /. {u -> 10, t -> 0.7, y -> 0.25, 
Z -> 1.7}) - (result/. {u -> -5, t -> 0.7, y -> 0.25, Z -> 1.7}) Out[109]= -0.080498 - 0.000454007 I
```

Does anyone know the reason? Thank you for your help

Comment: Take a look at `Plot[Re[result /. {t -> 7/10, y -> 1/4, Z -> 17/10}], {u, -5, 10}]` and you will see a discontinuity at the origin.

Comment: Unfortunately, `Integrate[
  1/(\[Pi]^3 (I u + y)) I (-1 + 
     t^2) (-(((1 - 6 t^2 + t^4 + 8 t Z - 
           4 Z^2) ArcTan[(-I + I t^2 + 2 t u - 2 u Z)/
           Sqrt[1 + t^4 + 4 t^3 y + 4 y Z + 4 Z^2 - 4 t (y + 2 Z) + 
             t^2 (2 - 4 y Z)]])/((-1 + 
           t^2) (1 + t^4 + 4 t^3 y + 4 y Z + 4 Z^2 - 4 t (y + 2 Z) + 
            t^2 (2 - 4 y Z))^(3/2)))), u, 
  Assumptions -> 
   u \[Element] Reals && t > -1 && t < 1 && y > -1 && y < 1 && Z > 1, 
  GenerateConditions -> True] // Simplify` produces the same result as yours.

Comment: How do you know that it is NIntegrate's result (and not Integrate's) that is wrong?

Comment: @Szabolcs If i differentiate result and simplify i get the original integrand, therefore the Integrate result is correct

Comment: The problem is using the indefinite integration result directly to compute the definite integral. As user64494 points out, it has a discontinuity at 0. This result is correct for both $u<0$ and for $u>0$, and thus suitable for definite integration _within_ those intervals. It will not give the correct results for an interval that contains 0. The `NIntegrate` result is actually correct. The lesson is that differentiation is not sufficient to check the "correctness" of this type of result, or at least to check its suitability for evaluating definite integrals.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To long for a comment:

MMA version 8.0 gives you an antiderivative that has no discontinuity (here called int1, your solution called int2)

```
int1 = -(I (1 - 6 t^2 + t^4 + 8 t Z - 4 Z^2) (\[Pi]^2 - 
   4 I \[Pi] ArcTanh[(1 - t^2 + 2 I t u - 2 I u Z)/Sqrt[
     1 + t^4 + 4 t^3 y + 4 y Z + 4 Z^2 - 4 t (y + 2 Z) + 
      t^2 (2 - 4 y Z)]] - 
   8 ArcTanh[(1 - t^2 + 2 I t u - 2 I u Z)/Sqrt[
     1 + t^4 + 4 t^3 y + 4 y Z + 4 Z^2 - 4 t (y + 2 Z) + 
      t^2 (2 - 4 y Z)]]^2 + 
   8 ArcTanh[(1 - t^2 + 2 I t u - 2 I u Z)/Sqrt[
     1 + t^4 + 4 t^3 y + 4 y Z + 4 Z^2 - 4 t (y + 2 Z) + 
      t^2 (2 - 4 y Z)]] ArcTanh[(1 - t^2 - 2 t y + 2 y Z)/Sqrt[
     1 + t^4 + 4 t^3 y + 4 y Z + 4 Z^2 - 4 t (y + 2 Z) + 
      t^2 (2 - 4 y Z)]] - 
   4 ArcTanh[(1 - t^2 - 2 t y + 2 y Z)/Sqrt[
     1 + t^4 + 4 t^3 y + 4 y Z + 4 Z^2 - 4 t (y + 2 Z) + 
      t^2 (2 - 4 y Z)]]^2 + 
   4 I \[Pi] Log[
     1 + E^(2 ArcTanh[(1 - t^2 + 2 I t u - 2 I u Z)/Sqrt[
        1 + t^4 + 4 t^3 y + 4 y Z + 4 Z^2 - 4 t (y + 2 Z) + 
         t^2 (2 - 4 y Z)]])] + 
   8 ArcTanh[(1 - t^2 + 2 I t u - 2 I u Z)/Sqrt[
     1 + t^4 + 4 t^3 y + 4 y Z + 4 Z^2 - 4 t (y + 2 Z) + 
      t^2 (2 - 4 y Z)]] Log[
     1 + E^(2 ArcTanh[(1 - t^2 + 2 I t u - 2 I u Z)/Sqrt[
        
        1 + t^4 + 4 t^3 y + 4 y Z + 4 Z^2 - 4 t (y + 2 Z) + 
         t^2 (2 - 4 y Z)]])] - 
   8 ArcTanh[(1 - t^2 + 2 I t u - 2 I u Z)/Sqrt[
     1 + t^4 + 4 t^3 y + 4 y Z + 4 Z^2 - 4 t (y + 2 Z) + 
      t^2 (2 - 4 y Z)]] Log[
     1 - E^(-2 ArcTanh[(1 - t^2 + 2 I t u - 2 I u Z)/Sqrt[
         1 + t^4 + 4 t^3 y + 4 y Z + 4 Z^2 - 4 t (y + 2 Z) + 
          t^2 (2 - 4 y Z)]] + 
       2 ArcTanh[(1 - t^2 - 2 t y + 2 y Z)/Sqrt[
         1 + t^4 + 4 t^3 y + 4 y Z + 4 Z^2 - 4 t (y + 2 Z) + 
          t^2 (2 - 4 y Z)]])] + 
   8 ArcTanh[(1 - t^2 - 2 t y + 2 y Z)/Sqrt[
     1 + t^4 + 4 t^3 y + 4 y Z + 4 Z^2 - 4 t (y + 2 Z) + 
      t^2 (2 - 4 y Z)]] Log[
     1 - E^(-2 ArcTanh[(1 - t^2 + 2 I t u - 2 I u Z)/Sqrt[
         1 + t^4 + 4 t^3 y + 4 y Z + 4 Z^2 - 4 t (y + 2 Z) + 
          t^2 (2 - 4 y Z)]] + 
       2 ArcTanh[(1 - t^2 - 2 t y + 2 y Z)/Sqrt[
         1 + t^4 + 4 t^3 y + 4 y Z + 4 Z^2 - 4 t (y + 2 Z) + 
          t^2 (2 - 4 y Z)]])] + 
   8 ArcTanh[(1 - t^2 + 2 I t u - 2 I u Z)/Sqrt[
     1 + t^4 + 4 t^3 y + 4 y Z + 4 Z^2 - 4 t (y + 2 Z) + 
      t^2 (2 - 4 y Z)]] Log[1/(
     2 Sqrt[((t - Z) (-I u + t (1 + u^2) - y + t^2 (I u + y) - Z -
          u^2 Z))/(
      1 + t^4 + 4 t^3 y + 4 y Z + 4 Z^2 - 4 t (y + 2 Z) + 
       t^2 (2 - 4 y Z))])] - 
   4 I \[Pi] Log[1/
     Sqrt[((t - Z) (-I u + t (1 + u^2) - y + t^2 (I u + y) - Z - 
        u^2 Z))/(
     1 + t^4 + 4 t^3 y + 4 y Z + 4 Z^2 - 4 t (y + 2 Z) + 
      t^2 (2 - 4 y Z))]] - 
   8 ArcTanh[(1 - t^2 + 2 I t u - 2 I u Z)/Sqrt[
     1 + t^4 + 4 t^3 y + 4 y Z + 4 Z^2 - 4 t (y + 2 Z) + 
      t^2 (2 - 4 y Z)]] Log[1/
     Sqrt[((t - Z) (-I u + t (1 + u^2) - y + t^2 (I u + y) - Z - 
        u^2 Z))/(
     1 + t^4 + 4 t^3 y + 4 y Z + 4 Z^2 - 4 t (y + 2 Z) + 
      t^2 (2 - 4 y Z))]] - 
   8 ArcTanh[(1 - t^2 + 2 I t u - 2 I u Z)/Sqrt[
     1 + t^4 + 4 t^3 y + 4 y Z + 4 Z^2 - 4 t (y + 2 Z) + 
      t^2 (2 - 4 y Z)]] Log[
     I Sinh[ArcTanh[(1 - t^2 + 2 I t u - 2 I u Z)/Sqrt[
         1 + t^4 + 4 t^3 y + 4 y Z + 4 Z^2 - 4 t (y + 2 Z) + 
          t^2 (2 - 4 y Z)]] - 
        ArcTanh[(1 - t^2 - 2 t y + 2 y Z)/Sqrt[
         1 + t^4 + 4 t^3 y + 4 y Z + 4 Z^2 - 4 t (y + 2 Z) + 
          t^2 (2 - 4 y Z)]]]] + 
   8 ArcTanh[(1 - t^2 + 2 I t u - 2 I u Z)/Sqrt[
     1 + t^4 + 4 t^3 y + 4 y Z + 4 Z^2 - 4 t (y + 2 Z) + 
      t^2 (2 - 4 y Z)]] Log[
     2 I Sinh[
       ArcTanh[(1 - t^2 + 2 I t u - 2 I u Z)/Sqrt[
         1 + t^4 + 4 t^3 y + 4 y Z + 4 Z^2 - 4 t (y + 2 Z) + 
          t^2 (2 - 4 y Z)]] - 
        ArcTanh[(1 - t^2 - 2 t y + 2 y Z)/Sqrt[
         1 + t^4 + 4 t^3 y + 4 y Z + 4 Z^2 - 4 t (y + 2 Z) + 
          t^2 (2 - 4 y Z)]]]] - 
   8 ArcTanh[(1 - t^2 - 2 t y + 2 y Z)/Sqrt[
     1 + t^4 + 4 t^3 y + 4 y Z + 4 Z^2 - 4 t (y + 2 Z) + 
      t^2 (2 - 4 y Z)]] Log[
     2 I Sinh[
       ArcTanh[(1 - t^2 + 2 I t u - 2 I u Z)/Sqrt[
         1 + t^4 + 4 t^3 y + 4 y Z + 4 Z^2 - 4 t (y + 2 Z) + 
          t^2 (2 - 4 y Z)]] - 
        ArcTanh[(1 - t^2 - 2 t y + 2 y Z)/Sqrt[
         1 + t^4 + 4 t^3 y + 4 y Z + 4 Z^2 - 4 t (y + 2 Z) + 
          t^2 (2 - 4 y Z)]]]] + 
   4 PolyLog[
     2, -E^(2 ArcTanh[(1 - t^2 + 2 I t u - 2 I u Z)/Sqrt[
        1 + t^4 + 4 t^3 y + 4 y Z + 4 Z^2 - 4 t (y + 2 Z) + 
         t^2 (2 - 4 y Z)]])] + 
   4 PolyLog[2, 
     E^(-2 ArcTanh[(1 - t^2 + 2 I t u - 2 I u Z)/Sqrt[
        
        1 + t^4 + 4 t^3 y + 4 y Z + 4 Z^2 - 4 t (y + 2 Z) + 
         t^2 (2 - 4 y Z)]] + 
      2 ArcTanh[(1 - t^2 - 2 t y + 2 y Z)/Sqrt[
        1 + t^4 + 4 t^3 y + 4 y Z + 4 Z^2 - 4 t (y + 2 Z) + 
         t^2 (2 - 4 y Z)]])]))/(8 \[Pi]^3 (1 + t^4 + 4 t^3 y + 
  4 y Z + 4 Z^2 - 4 t (y + 2 Z) + t^2 (2 - 4 y Z))^(3/2))
```

Have a look

```
Plot[Evaluate[
   Through[{Re, Im}[int1 /. {t -> 0.7, y -> 0.25, Z -> 1.7}]]], {u, -5,
  10}]

Plot[Evaluate[
   Through[{Re, Im}[int2 /. {t -> 0.7, y -> 0.25, Z -> 1.7}]]], {u, -5,
  10}]
```

**Edit**

A workaround for your result (my int2) is to subtract the discontinuity at u == zero.

```
(int2 /. {u -> 10, t -> 0.7, y -> 0.25, Z -> 1.7}) - 
Limit[(int2 /. {t -> 0.7, y -> 0.25, Z -> 1.7}), u -> 0, 
Direction -> -1] + 
Limit[(int2 /. {t -> 0.7, y -> 0.25, Z -> 1.7}), u -> 0, 
Direction -> 1] - (int2 /. {u -> -5, t -> 0.7, y -> 0.25, Z -> 1.7})

(*   -0.0579211 - 0.000454007 I   *)
```

Comment: Did you try to evaluate `int1` by `{t -> 0.7, y -> 0.25, Z -> 1.7,u->10}` and by  `{t -> 0.7, y -> 0.25, Z -> 1.7,u->-5}` ?

Comment: Of course. Gives the same result as `NIntegrate`